# Question about Morse inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, morse-theory

Helli , i have question 
i Morse inequality why $$\sum_{q\geq0} M_q(a,b) t^q =\sum_{q\geq 0}\beta_q(a,b)t^q+(1+t)Q(t),$$ where $Q(t)$ is a polynomial with nonnegative integer coefficients

implise that:

1) $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^{q-j}M_j(a,b)\geq \sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^{q-j} \beta_j(a,b),q=0,1,2,...$ and

2) $\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}(-1)^q M_q(a,b)=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} (-1)^q \beta_q(a,b)$

Comment: Do we know anything about $Q$? Its degree?

Comment: no, but when $t=-1$ $(1+t)Q(t)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since all the coefficients of $(1+t)Q(t)$ are non-negative integers, the initial equation says that $M_k(a,b)\ge\beta_k(a,b)$ for all $k$, and for all but a finite set of $k$, $M_k(a,b)=\beta_k(a,b)$. This implies 1).

If we set $t=-1$, the initial equation is just 2).

Comment: why $M_k(a,b)=\beta_k(a,b)$ in a finite set of $k$ ? please so why at infinity there = ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: just compare the coefficients of $t^k$. For all $k$, we have $M_k(a,b)\ge\beta_k(a,b)$, then for all $k$ larger than the degree of $(1+t)Q(t)$, we have $M_k(a,b)=\beta_k(a,b)$.

Comment: i dont understand "then for k larger than the degree of $(1+t)Q(t)$"?? i found in the book that $Q(t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}r_k t^k$ and that $M_k$ and $\beta_k$ are finite for all $k$ and vanich for $k$ large

Comment: @Vrouvrou: In the question, you said that $Q$ was a polynomial, so it has a finite degree. If the book says that $Q(t)=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}r_kt^k$, then it does not look like a polynomial.

Comment: look at the chat please , they say that $Q(t)$ is a polynomial

Comment: please why in the first we have $(-1)^{q-j}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Where did that come from? That wasn't there before. I have no idea what $q$ is in the first place. I don't have the book; you may have to look there to find out more.

Comment: yes, i edited my question if you have the book is K.C chang Infinite dimensional morse theory and multiple solution problems

Comment: so i dont undestand why $\sum_{q\geq0} M_q(a,b) t^q =\sum_{q\geq 0}\beta_q(a,b)t^q+(1+t)Q(t)$ implise that  $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^{q-j}M_j(a,b)\geq \sum_{j=0}^q (-1)^{q-j} \beta_j(a,b), q=0,1,2...$

Comment: This goes beyond what you have given in the question. I don't have that book nor do I have any further knowledge of $M_k$ or $\beta_k$. For general series, the inequality does not follow from the equation given; it must have something to do with some undisclosed properties of $M_k$ and $\beta_k$.